# Jquery 2.1.0 with ScrollTo

Tags: jquery, parallax, scrollto

I need to use Jquery 2.1.0 and have been using http://www.ianlunn.co.uk/plugins/jquery-parallax/ which uses `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js` but it seems that there are compatibility issues with the plugins. I have updated all versions of the plugins on this page and although I get the usual parallax scrolling using the scrollbars, the #nav element is no longer activates the `$('#nav').localScroll(800);` function, only the mouse and scrolling bars do.

Has anyone encountered issues using the latest version of Jquery with ScrollTo/parallax scrolling?

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: Nope, firebug console is totally blank.

Comment: Ok, I opened the browser console instead (why doesn't the firebug console never work?) and I get:Error in parsing value for 'left'.  Declaration dropped. jquery-parallax.htm
   `Error in parsing value for 'top'.  Declaration dropped. jquery-parallax.htm
Error in parsing value for 'margin-top'.  Declaration dropped.`